# Passing down Values in React Spring + Styled Components (interpolating)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components, react-spring

I have a Donut Button. It's a **styled component** + **react-spring's** *animated*:

```
const Donut = styled(animated.button)`
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -50px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: pink;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px black;
  color: blue;`;
```

I initialise react-spring with hooks, like so:

```
const [{ y }, set] = useSpring(() => ({
    y: 50,
    config: config.wobbly
  }));
```

And then somewhere, there's a div which sets & unsets the `y` value

```
  <div
        onMouseEnter={() => set({ y: -50, opacity: 1 })}
        onMouseLeave={() => set({ y: 50, opacity: 0 })}
      >
```

I put everything into my component like so:

```
<Donut style={{ transform: y.interpolate(v => `translateY(${v}%`) }} />
```

**So far everything works.** It moves up and down.

**My Question:**

I'd like to not use inline-styles. So I want to move everything into the styled component.

I have tried this:

```
<Donut y={y} />
```

and in my styled component added this:

```
${props => props.y.interpolate(v => `transform: translateY(${v}%`)};
```

It doesn't work. Any ideas?

*PS: `props.y` **does** exist in the styled component, and it seems to be getting an **Animated** object, not a single value. So I must be doing something wrong. All the tutorials online that I've found were a bit more basic though and not about interpolating with react-spring + styled-components*

Comment: I think you could not do this. useSpring return value is not a style even when you not use interpolation. It seems like a style, but it is not exactly that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a way that nicely integrates with styled-components, - I've seen it before in a project, I believe. Can't remember where though. And I just can't find anything online. But yeah, the way I'm trying it here is clearly incorrect :(

Comment: Good luck, I will check back.

Comment: Did you try to wrap it with `css` from styled-component?

Comment: I guess not - What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @R.Kohlisch Hey, any updates on this, have you found a better way than style prop?